Using PSweight for multilevel variable analysis to calculate IPW
I have a data frame named "df", with a treatment variable named "treatment", which is categorical with three values (0 to 2), I also have five other covariates (cov1 to cov5; where cov2 and cov3 are factors, rest is continuous), and a binary outcome named "outcome_var" with values of 0 or 1.
Using the Psweight package in R, I want to run a code to estimate treatment effect of the treatment variable on the outcome variable with adjustment for the cofounders
I attempted this code; and got an error:
#Loading libraries 
library(PSweight)
library(tidyverse)

#Data with no missing values 
df<- df%>%
   na.omit()

# Ensure proper formula usage with factors
ps.mult <- treatment~ cov1+ as.factor(cov2) + as.factor(cov3) + cov4 + cov5

# Applying SumStat to obtain the propensity score estimates and assess the weighted covariate balance
bal.mult <- SumStat(
  ps.formula = ps.mult,
  weight = "IPW",
  data = df)

ERROR encountered:
Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors

I tried multiple things from making sure I have no missing values in my dataset to addressing factor values as they are.
